# Boton Hamburger y modal bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Me podrían ayudar con el Hamburger ya no funciona en el primer click al cerrar el modal de bootstrap 4

al cerrar modal desde cualquiera de las 3 formas (boton cerrar dentro del modal, click fuera del modal o presionar el boton burger) el boton burger no cambia la X pero solo en la primera vez ya después trabaja correctamente. eso es lo que quiero arreglar.

Aquí el codigo

https://codepen.io/Angeloriel/pen/YoPXmK

Gracias!

Comment: hola oriel que tratas de hacer con el codigo de JS? tienes un boton cerrar en la parte inferior, con eso bastaria para que no uses el burger boton

Comment: Yo veo el código funcionar sin problema

Comment: al cerrar modal desde cualquiera de las 3 formas (boton cerrar dentro del modal , click fuera del modal o presionar el boton burger) el boton burger no cambia la X pero solo en la primera vez ya después trabaja correctamente. eso es lo que quiero arreglar

Comment: funciona bien de las 3 formas

Comment: si pero al cerrar por primera vez el modal no hay cambio en el botón burger "se queda  marcado X" pero después ya funciona correctamente yo solo quiero arreglar lo del primer cierre que se queda en X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listo nadie me pudo ayudar en este caso pero lo único que hice fue agregar `isOpened = true;`
y cambiando else por if quedando así.

```
            if (isOpened == true) {
                $('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {
                    trigger.removeClass('is-open');
                    trigger.addClass('is-closed');
                    isOpened = true;
                })
            }
```